# Write the shortest program that generates the most compiler warnings and errors

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, error-message

### The challenge:

Write a very short program that, when compiled, creates the most amount of compiler warnings and errors. It can be written in any programming language.

### Scoring:

The score is determined by this equation: `errors_and_warnings_length/code_length`. Highest score wins.

### Example:

The C# program `class` is 5 chars long and generates 3 warnings, which is a score of (1/5)*3 = 0.6.

### EDIT:

Because of some confusion, programs have to be at least 1 char long. Otherwise it would get a score of infinity.

Comment: While I like the concept, I find the metric a little worrisome. What compiler? What settings (especially with regard to warnings)? I mean `gcc -Wall -pedantic` is very different from plain ol` `gcc` is different from `tcc` is presumably different from some other c compiler.

Comment: Just get a compiler in Russian, or German, you get some LONG errors(no pun intended)

Comment: I'd love to see answers in languages other than C/C++.

Comment: I would've liked it if the challenge was to generate as many *different* errors as possible

Comment: Ahem. Otherwise its score would be *undefined*.

Comment: On a related note, here's a link to the grand C++ error explosion competition
http://tgceec.tumblr.com/post/74534916370/results-of-the-grand-c-error-explosion

Answer (score 101, accepted):

### GCC, score 2<sup>200</sup> / 36 ≈ 4.5 × 10<sup>58</sup>

```
#include __FILE__
#include __FILE__
```

I have not actually finished compiling this code, but based on testing and simple mathematics, it should produce a total of 2<sup>200</sup> `#include nested too deeply` errors.

Of course, the program is trivially extensible.  Adding a third line brings the score up to **3<sup>200</sup> / 54 ≈ 4.9 × 10<sup>93</sup>**.  Four lines give **4<sup>200</sup> / 72 ≈ 3.6 × 10<sup>118</sup>**, and so on.

Comment: Very clever answer. +1

Comment: Very clever I agree, but I'd count that as 1 error ("nested too deeply"), not a separate error for each line of the backtrace.

Comment: Wow, very clever. Looks like we got a very clear winner!

Comment: @Kevin: Just to be clear, it should produce that error 2²⁰⁰ times, once for each possible path by which the nesting limit can be reached.  The fact that each error _also_ includes 200 lines of backtrace just makes the output even more verbose.

Comment: Hmm. I could swear when I tried it last night gcc bailed after 1 error, but it appears to be running printing more now.  Objection withdrawn. Incidentally, is 200 from the c standard?

Comment: @Kevin: I've no idea, but that's what the limit seems to be for GCC.

Comment: @Kevin Per http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/cpp/Implementation-limits.html : "We impose an arbitrary limit of 200 levels [of nested `#include`], to avoid runaway recursion. The standard requires at least 15 levels."

Comment: ... and it's a good thing I don't hack on GCC anymore or I would feel I had to find some way to detect this scenario and bail out earlier. ;-)

Answer (score 53):

### C, 0 characters - Score=(1/0)*1=Infinity

generates 1 error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note: http://ideone.com/xdoJyA

Comment: 1/0 is undefined, not "infinity".

Comment: @Frank, that depends on the number system.

Comment: Fitting answer to this question.

Comment: +1 Even if 1/0 is undefined, it's demonstrably larger than one divided by any larger number.  0 takes the cake.

Comment: @jnm2 not sure about that. 1/0 is undefined and, although right side approaches +infinity, that doesn't make 1/0 defined at all.

Comment: Limit doesn't say a whole lot about the value in the point. That only holds true if the function is continuous in that point. Take for example the sign function.

Comment: Not to mention, @jnm2, by your logic 1/0 also is demonstrably smaller than 1 divided by any smaller number than 0. Making it 1/-1 = -1 > 1/0 > 1 = 1/1 ?

Comment: Note that you can turn the link error into a compiler error. Using gcc's `-pedantic` switch wil give you: `empty.c:1: warning: ISO C forbids an empty translation unit`.

Comment: Since the domain is positive, I think what I said makes sense.  Theory is fun but I think we need some common sense here.  The most compiler errors for the least amount of code, remember.  The limit is obvious.

Comment: 1.0/0.0 = +INF, at least according to IEEE 754 :)  So you just have to do the calculation in floating point.

Comment: A zero-sized C code was accepted as the winner in the IOCCC, as the shortest self-replicating program, so it's a good precedence to accept it here. (the rules were, as usually, changed after that submission, but it still counts)

Comment: In Maths, 1/0 is infinity and it is 0/0 which is undefined.

Comment: I've modified the rules. Sorry, but your program is disqualified. +1 for the idea, though.

Comment: @manojlds Incorrect. The *limit* is, in some cases, +infinity. However imagine the limit of 1/(-(x^2)) when approaching zero, suddenly it's 1/0 = -infinity. And what about 1/sgn(x)? Now the limit coming from the positive side is +1 and the limit from the negative side is -1.

Comment: @WardMuylaert what you say is right, sgn(x) matters, but in this case x is the number of characters of code, which cannot be negative, so the limit must come from +1 side. Also, when I wrote infinity there all that was on my head was 1/10 < 1/1 < 1/0.1 < 1/0.01 < 1/0.001 <.....<1/0. :P

Comment: 1/0=∞ in arithmatic on the [real projective line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line). So like it was said before, this is just a matter of the number system you are using.

Answer (score 20):

### GCC, score 5586.6 (and more if needed)

179 chars, 1000003 warnings/errors (using `-Wall`)

```
#define E a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
#define D E,E,E,E,E,E,E,E,E,E
#define C D,D,D,D,D,D,D,D,D,D
#define B C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C
#define A B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B
_(){A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A}
```

This can be extended arbitrarily, of course. For example, using 10 `#define`s instead of 5 and a length of 20 "calls" instead of 10 would lead to a score of about (20**10)/(179*4) = 14301675977.65 (and would take quite some time to run ;)

Comment: Using `#define X(A) A,A,A,A,A,A,A` and `X(X(X(X(X(X(A))))))` you can duplicate code much faster.

Comment: An application of the [billion laughs attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs_attack), nice.

Answer (score 13):

### GCC twice, 86

22 chars, 1898 errors+warnings on my system.
I'm sure this approach can be much improved, by choosing longer files with shorter names.

```
#include</usr/bin/gcc>
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/gdb` is significantly larger (5.5M vs 760K), but `/vmlinuz` at 5.6M might be your best bet.

Answer (score 13):

### HQ9++, 1 (limit of (n+29)/n)

The following emits the warning `Warning: this is not a quine` for each Q in the code.

```
QQQQQ...Q
Warning: this is not a quine
```

Small is good, right?  Hmm...

Comment: FWIW, this is a joke.  If that wasn't obvious.

Comment: As far as jokes go, this is a good one. +1

Answer (score 11):

### C, .727

11 chars, 5 errors, 3 warnings, (1/11)*8 = .727273

```
m(;){@,x}2
```

`cc -g -Wall    er.c   -o er
er.c:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before ';' token
er.c:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int'
er.c: In function 'm':
er.c:1: error: stray '@' in program
er.c:1: error: expected expression before ',' token
er.c:1: error: 'x' undeclared (first use in this function)
er.c:1: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
er.c:1: error: for each function it appears in.)
er.c:1: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
er.c:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
er.c: At top level:
er.c:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant`

Comment: I count 5 errors, plus 3 warnings

Comment: I suppose you're right. I was counting the "error:" and "warning:" strings.

Comment: I think you win if we only count different errors/warnings.

Comment: If -Werror is used on the command line, warnings are promoted to errors.  And also, which C compiler used will affect the number of reported errors *(or if -Werror is available, etc.)*  One might argue the command line length for invocation might be counted as part of the "program" length... and each compiler version on each platform is a separate category.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

### NASM, score 63/40 * 2^32 ≈ 2.905 * 10^19

```
%rep 1<<32
%rep 1<<32
!
%endrep
%endrep
```

Will output `c.asm:3: error: label or instruction expected at start of line` 2^64 times. Again this is easily extensible to much bigger outputs.

Answer (score 5):

**C++98 (211 bytes)** g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~12.04) 5.2.1 0151031

I wanted to see how well I could do in C++ without using the preprocessor at all. This program produces 2,139,390,572 bytes of output, most of which is a single error message.

```
template<int i,class S,class T>struct R{typedef R<i,typename R<i-1,S,S>::D,typename R<i-1,S,S>::D>D;};template<class S,class T>struct R<0,S,T>{typedef S D;};void f(){R<27,float,R<24,int*const*,int>::D>::D&E=4;}

me@Basement:~/src/junk$ ls -l a.C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 211 Apr 27 21:44 a.C
me@Basement:~/src/junk$ g++-5 a.C -fmax-errors=1 2>a.C.errors.txt
me@Basement:~/src/junk$ ls -l a.C.errors.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2139390572 Apr 27 22:01 a.C.errors.txt
```

Ungolfed:

```
template <int i, class S, class T>
struct R {
    typedef R<i, typename R<i-1,S,S>::D, typename R<i-1,S,S>::D> D;
};
template <class S, class T>
struct R<0, S, T> {
    typedef S D;
};
void f() {
    R<27, float, R<24, int*const*, int>::D>::D &E = 4;
}
```

This program works by defining a recursive struct template R which holds a typedef D containing two copies of R. This results in an type name which grows exponentially, which is printed out in full in the error message. Unfortunately, g++ seems to choke while attempting to print an error message longer than (1<<31) bytes. 2,139,390,572 bytes was the closest I could get to the limit without going over. I'm curious if anyone can adjust the recursion limits and parameter types `27, float, 24, int*const*` to get closer to the limit (or find a compiler which can print an even longer error message).

Excerpts from the error message:

```
a.C: In function ‘void f()’:
a.C:1:208:  error:  invalid  initialization  of non-const reference of type
‘R<27, float, R<24, R<23, R<22, R<21, R<20, R<19, R<18, R<17, R<16, R<15,
R<14,  R<13, R<12, R<11, R<10, R<9, R<8, R<7, R<6, R<5, R<4, R<3, R<2, R<1,
int* const*, int* const*>, R<1, int* const*, int* const*> >, R<2, R<1, int*
const*,  int*  const*>,  R<1, int* const*, int* const*> > >, R<3, R<2, R<1,
int* const*, int* const*>, R<1, int* const*, int* const*> >, R<2, R<1, int*
const*,  int* const*>, R<1, int* const*, int* const*> > > >, R<4, R<3, R<2,
R<1, int* const*, int* const*>, R<1,
...
int*  const*,  int*  const*>  > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >
>::D& {aka R<27, R<26, R<25, R<24, R<23,  R<22,  R<21,  R<20,  R<19,  R<18,
R<17,  R<16,  R<15,  R<14, R<13, R<12, R<11, R<10, R<9, R<8, R<7, R<6, R<5,
R<4, R<3, R<2, R<1, float, float>, R<1, float, float> >, R<2,  R<1,  float,
float>,  R<1,  float, float> > >, R<3, R<2, R<1, float, float>, R<1, float,
float> >, R<2, R<1, float, float>, R<1, float, float> > > >, R<4, 
...
, R<1, float, float>, R<1, float, float> > >, R<3, R<2, R<1, float, float>,
R<1, float, float> >, R<2, R<1, float, float>, R<1, float, float> > > > > >
>  >  >  >  >  >  > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >&}’ from an rvalue of type
‘int’
    template<int    i,class   S,class   T>struct   R{typedef   R<i,typename
R<i-1,S,S>::D,typename  R<i-1,S,S>::D>D;};template<class  S,class  T>struct
R<0,S,T>{typedef                         S                         D;};void
f(){R<27,float,R<24,int*const*,int>::D>::D&E=4;}


                                                        ^
compilation terminated due to -fmax-errors=1.
```

<strike>2,139,390,572 bytes / 211 bytes = 10,139,291.8</strike>

Comment: This is why I always use [STLfilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html)... Welcome to PPCG! This is a great first submission!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems I misunderstood the challenge; it seems submissions are scored by the number of error messages, not the byte count. Obviously my 1 error entry is not very competitive. Perhaps my answer should be moved [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/generate-the-longest-error-message-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

### Rust, 206 chars, 2<sup>20</sup>+2 errors, score 5090, tunable.

```
macro_rules! e {
    ($e:expr, $($es:expr),+) => {
    compile_error!(stringify!($e, $($es),+));
        e! { $(a + $es),+ }
        e! { $(b + $es),+ }
    };
}
e! {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

And you can actually see it finish compilation, in about 3 minutes for me:

```
error: could not compile `a` due to 1048578 previous errors
```

Like the C `#include __FILE__` example above, it is tunable, but

- if you want to go beyond 2<sup>256</sup>, you need to set `#![recursion_limit = "9999999"]`
- rustc will OOM long before you can reach that
- longer expressions mean slower execution, so the more errors you want, the slower they will be printed

What I actually wanted to do is implement the Péter's variant of the Ackermann function. But I don't quite grok macros well enough to do that with the unary encoding. Anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 1/1 = 1

```
A
```

Generates the error `Syntax Error in 0:1`

Comment: SB only ever generates one error at a time, so this is really the only answer you can make.