# Largest Error Message in 100 bytes

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, busy-beaver, error-message

The goal is to raise the error message with the most bytes! The error message may not be generated by the program itself, such as Python's `raise`. errors that do not terminate the program are not allowed unless they do not show an error message.

Here is an example in python that raises 243041 bytes of error code:

```python
def a(m):
    try:-''
    except:
        if m>0:
            a(m-1)
        else:-''
a(900)
```

you can try it [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFRI1fTiksBCEqKKq101dXB7NSK5NSCEog4CGSmKeTaGSD4IADUqWuoCRdKzSlOBetP1LA0MND8/x8A).

Comment: Is the scoring criteria the length of the error message? And is 100 bytes a limit on code length, or do our solutions have to be exactly 100 bytes?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing the scoring criteria is the length of the error message and 100 bytes is a limit.

Comment: Since your example is just raising the same error a bunch of times, what's stopping me from doing something like `while(true) { 1/0; }` and claiming 'infinite' error bytes?

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman because after one error, the program terminates.

Comment: That's not true for all languages; many languages will continue execution after an exception is thrown

Comment: I editted the question to not allow errors that do not terminate.

Comment: If my language's error messages include the erroring code, does that count?

Comment: @Adám, yes, that counts

Comment: This feels less like a code challenge and more like a challenge to find the language with the most verbose error messages.

Comment: So, maybe I'm missing something about Python, but doesn't your example utilize errors that do not terminate the code execution, seeing as they are trapped in a try block? If that's so, is it allowed to utilize errors that do not terminate code execution, so long as the code does eventually terminate; or is the example rendered invalid by this clarification?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of really any challenge involving printing big numbers e.g. [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/31695/66833) or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable), as answers aren't going to do anything other than "generate big number, repeat string that many times, execute" as having a long string is usually an error. I'd VTC as a duplicate of one of them if I hadn't already VTCed as unclear, but even if this is clarified and reopened, I still believe it should stay closed

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I agree - I deleted my answer here and moved it to one of those questions, but what reason should it be closed for? It's not an exact duplicate, right? Some answers may find ways to do it other than just finding the largest number.

Comment: @user In it's current state, I stand by my VTC as unclear, as the challenge needs a proper description of an "error", but challenges don't need to be exact duplicates to be closed as one another

Comment: [Related: Generate the longest error message in C++.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1956/52210)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), \$\approx\$A(A(A(9,9),A(9,9)),A(A(9,9),A(99,99))) where A is the Ackermann function,or limited by RAM

```python
A=lambda m,n:m and A(m-1,n<1or A(m,n-1))or-~n
a='.'*(A(A(A(9,9),A(9,9)),A(A(9,9),A(99,99))))
exec(a)
```

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39E2JzE3KSVRIVcnzypXITEvRcFRI1fXUCfPxjC/CMTWydM11NTML9Kty@NKtFXXU9fScARDSx1LTR0IBaIRAkAaKKSpyZVakZqskaj5/z8A)

Stole the Ackermann function from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40151/89930).

More manageable version to demonstrate:

```python
A=lambda m,n:m and A(m-1,n<1or A(m,n-1))or-~n
a='.'*(9999)
exec(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39E2JzE3KSVRIVcnzypXITEvRcFRI1fXUCfPxjC/CMTWydM11NTML9Kty@NKtFXXU9fSsAQCTa7UitRkjUTN//8B)

Admittedly I'm not certain this approach is arbitrarily extendible in practice.

Comment: I think you can squeeze in a few more `9`s, or one more `A()`, by moving the second line into the `exec` and eliminating `a=`. But either way it seems that the recursion limit needs to be increased (massively) to produce the intended error. I gather that this can be done (in principle) via `sys.setrecursionlimit`, but I'm not sure whether there's a policy on counting the bytes required to do this.

Comment: @Dingus I haven't done the math, but I am going to confidently say that no computer that is even theoretically capable of existing in our universe could handle the amount of recursion necessary to execute this answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), a huge number \$ + 1605\$ bytes

```
ȷ!!!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡!¡”.xŒV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///EdkVFxUMLBwl61DBXr@LopLD//wE)

More specifically, this outputs an error message which is 1605 bytes long, plus two occurrences of massive chains of `...`. Unsurprisingly, this does not actually show an error really no matter where you run it, but in theory it will

I'm not entirely sure just how large this number is, aside from being significantly larger than \$1000!_{1000!_{(1000!)!}}\$, where \$n!_k\$ represents applying \$!\$ to \$n\$ \$k\$ times e.g. \$3!_3 = ((3!)!)! = (6!)! = 720! = 2.6 \times 10^{1746}\$

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), limited only by available memory

Full program. Causes error message a bit bigger than twice the given number.

```apl
⍎2e6⍴⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@j3j6jVLNHvVse9U11BAn9LwAA)

`⎕A` the uppercase **A**lphabet

`2e6⍴` cyclically **r**eshape to a string with two million characters

`⍎` execute

This causes an error of the form:

```
VALUE ERROR: Undefined name: string
      string
      ∧
```

Comment: if you theoretically had an infinite memory, how long would the error be?

Comment: @someone Simply increase the number (`2e6` in the post) until the memory fills.

Comment: if you increased the number enough, it would be bigger that one hundred bytes, which is the maximum allowed size, so you can't enlarge the number forever.

Comment: @someone The universe [is estimated](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/35924) to be able to contain about 10¹²² bits, i.e. about 10¹²² bytes, so since we're using exponential format, `1e6` would simple need to be replaced by the 2 bytes longer `1e122`, possibly adding a few bytes for more significant digits, once the exact number is known.

Comment: Given the limit is 100 bytes, surely something like `⍎9e999...99⍴⎕A` with enough `9`s to get to 100 bytes would be the best score?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I don't know APL, but could repeated exponentiation or factorials be better than a bunch of consecutive 9's?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing If you want to go that route, then use `⎕A/⍨` followed by the largest number producible in 95 bytes. Needless to say, that'll be [quite big](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18033/43319). Error message will be just over 52 times longer.

Comment: @79037662 [Yes.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18033/43319).

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing if you did that, then you would have about 9^10^95 *2 bytes in the error message

Answer (score 0):

### Java 11, repeat error message [2<sup>31</sup> - 1] times

[String's Maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/816142/14940971) in Java is [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) i.e. == 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, or less, it depends on *server max memory size* and other conditions otherwise it produces [`OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).

1. You can throw some [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Error.html) with the certain message, for example:

   ```java
   throw new Error("fatal".repeat(Integer.MAX_VALUE/5));
   ```

   Number of times to [`repeat`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l3129) is [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) / 5 - because `"fatal"` is 5 chars.
2. You can return something like this. It is not the error itself, but the error message:

   ```java
   for(int i=0;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++){
       String m="fatal"+i;
       out.println(m.repeat(Integer.MAX_VALUE/m.length()-1));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), \$4\times(9\times10^{307})^{32}+47\$ bytes

```sh
alias r=repeat\ 9e307
r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r a+=1111
let $a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKg68ZlZWOj7unu5x/kqv4/MSczsVihyLYotSA1sSRGwTLV2MCcq0iBMpiobWsIBFw5QAtVEv9DLOOC2AG0wlABwbQGqbWGKgQA)

Generates a string containing \$4\times(9\times10^{307})^{32}\$ ones, then tries to evaluate it as an integer.

In practice you will obviously run into memory limitations. Here is a more manageable version:

```sh
repeat 9e1 repeat 9e1 a+=1
let $a
```

- `alias r=repeat\ 9e307` allows us to nest more `repeats` in the 100 bytes we have
- `9e307` (\$9\times10^{307}\$) is the largest compact finite floating-point number `zsh` might be able to count to